# Регулярное выражение на вхождения на границах строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть в начале и в конце строки одинаковая часть. Например:

> `( "Вересковская Юлия" ) var tmp = "З@*B@L@"; function test (name) {    alert("Меня" + tmp + " " + name);} test ( "Вересковская Юлия" );`

Обратите внимание на то, что в строке повторяется "( "Вересковская Юлия" )". Но убираться должно то, что идентично совпадает с концом строки. Т.е. в начале строки мне нужно убрать '( "Вересковская Юлия" )'.

Comment: Если ответ ниже помог решить проблему, пожалуйста, отметьте его как решение, поставив галочку напротив.

Answer (score 1):

Спец символ ^ - для замены в начале, $ - для замены в конце.

```
var begin = /^John Smith/;
var end = /John Smith$/;

var str = "John Smith and John Smith";

alert(str.replace(begin, ""));
alert(str.replace(end, ""));
```

Comment: `str.replace(/^(.+)(.*)\1(.*)$/, "$2$1$3")`